# How do I detect where is corrupted in a power point file?

Tags: powerpoint

I have a power point file(`.pptx`) generated by a program that copies xml files and content files in a slide to other slides. It simply extracts xml files and content files from original power point file and then copies xml files, finally compresses the files as a zip file and renames the file to `xxxxx.pptx`. (The xml files I mentioned here is, of course, about `Office Open XML`)

When I open this file in `Keynote` on Mac OS X, it works well. No error happened.

However when I use `PowerPoint` application on Mac OS X, the app says "PowerPoint found a problem with content in xxxxx.pptx"

I think there are differences between PowerPoint specs and Keynote specs, so I need to apply the generated pptx file to the PowerPoint specs.

But, the error does not say WHERE or WHAT ERROR IS OCCURRED, but says there are some errors in that file.

So I cannot look for where is damaged in the generated file!

How do I detect the errors in the file or validate the format of it?

I do not want to get 'restore tools' but 'error detection tools'.

Answer (score 1):

I simply used `Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool`.

In my situation, it said the `Content-Type` of xml files was different from expected one when I opened the pptx file. Soon, it occurred to me I forgot to change the data in `[Content_Types].xml`

After I fixed it, the file is opened without problems now!!

This app also shows codes in `C#` and validate each xml files individually.

Download Link is here ->
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425